Riez sequences and frames of subspaces, provided an orthonormal basis
Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ and a sequence $\lbrace f_n\rbrace\subset\mathcal H$, we say that it is a frame for $\mathcal H$ if there are constants $A,B>0$ such that $A\|f\|^2\leq \sum |\langle f,f_n\rangle|^2\leq B\|f\|^2$ for every $f\in\mathcal H$. Similarly, if we just have the upper bound, we say $\lbrace f_n\rbrace$ is a Bessel sequence. Finally, we say $\lbrace f_n\rbrace$ is a Riesz sequence if it is a Bessel sequence and there are constants $C,D>0$ such that
$$ C\|\lbrace c_n\rbrace\|^2_{l^2}\leq\left\|\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}c_nf_n\right\|^2_{\mathcal H}\leq D \|\lbrace c_n\rbrace\|^2_{l^2}$$
for any sequence in $l^2$. Now suppose I have an orthonormal basis $\lbrace e_n\rbrace$ for $\mathcal H$. Let $S$ be a closed subspace of $\mathcal H$ and denote by $S^\perp$ its orthogonal complement. Furthermore, denote by $P_S$ and $P_{S^\perp}$ the respective orthogonal projections. Let $N_1, N_2$ be a partition of $\mathbb N$. Now I want to show that $\lbrace P_S e_n\in N_1\rbrace$ is a frame for $S$ if and only if $\lbrace P_{S^\perp}e_n:n\in N_2\rbrace$ is a Riesz sequence for $S^\perp$. I am struggling to prove this or simpply get an intuition on why this should be true, as the information we have is about two sequences which apparently have not much relation whit each other. All I have managed to prove, in both directions, is the upper bound for the square sum of scalar products, but I don't even need the hypothesis to show this. Indeed, if $f\in S^\perp$,
$$\sum_{n\in N_2}|\langle f, P_{S^\perp}e_n\rangle|^2=\sum_{n\in N_2}|\langle f, e_n\rangle|^2=\|f\|^2-\sum_{n\in N_1} |\langle f, e_n\rangle|^2\leq \|f\|^2.$$
Similarly, if $f\in S$,
$$\sum_{n\in N_1}|\langle f, P_{S}e_n\rangle|^2\leq\|f\|^2.$$
I do not really know how to prove the rest of the bounds. My main problem is that I don't see how to use the hypothesis on one of the sets, when on the other I am taking the projections of a complementary set...

Complete your definitions with the use of $B.$

@LetacGérard oops, sorry, done
